# Form usestate within reusable modal component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, use-state, use-reducer

I have a reusable modal component which I'm trying to use to take user input for updating their personal information.

The content of the modal is set from a useReducer hook like so;

```js
const [modalState, modalDispatch] = useReducer(modalReducer, {
    heading: '',
    confirmButtonText: '',
    confirmButtonAction: '',
    show: false,
  });

  const dispatchModalAction = (action) => {
    modalDispatch({
      type: action,
    });
  };

const modalReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case PI:
        return {
          heading: 'Edit Personal Information',
          confirmButtonText: 'Submit',
          confirmButtonAction: () => console.log('Edit PI'),
          show: true,
          content: (
            <form>
              <div className="flex flex-col mb-4">
                <div className=" relative">
                  <label for="editMyPhone">
                    Phone{' '}
                    <span className="text-small text-red-500">(Required)</span>
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="tel"
                    id="editMyPhone"
                    name="newMyPhone"
                    value={myPhoneInput}
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      console.log(e.target.value);
                      setMyPhoneInput(e.target.value);
                      console.log({ myPhoneInput });
                    }}
                    className="rounded-lg flex-1 appearance-none border border-gray-300 w-full py-2 px-4 bg-white text-gray-700 placeholder-gray-400 shadow-sm text-base focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-purple-600 focus:border-transparent"
                    required
                  ></input>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          ),
        };
      
    }
  };
```

As you can see I have a state setter function on the onChange of each input field in the form. These useState hooks are declared in the parent component. As far as I can tell the modal component is able to access these state setting functions (as when I change the function names to something incorrect it throws an error about the function not existing), but currently when I type in the fields (which correctly populate with the initial values from useState) I'm able to append only one character to the state, and the value in the field does not update, just the state I see in dev tools.

Comment: It seems to me that your child component is not updating its content since it handles its own state (the reducer) which is telling it what it should render, even when you're updating the parent state. Why are you doing this? It would be better for your code to return the form and handle the states in your parent component

Comment: @SimonDX In answer to 'why I'm doing this', because this is my first time using useReducer and I've clearly still got a ways to go!

What would you suggest when you say 'have your code return the form'?

Answer (score 0):

`useReducer` is a better way to handle states when your app uses tons of it, in this case you can set it in your parent component and pass the corresponding values to your Modal.

```
function myReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'personal info':
      return {
        heading: payload.heading,
        confirmButtonText: payload.text,
        confirmButtonAction: payload.func,
        show: payload.display,
      };
    default:
      // Do something
  }
}

export default function ParentComponent() {
  const [myState, dispatch] = useReducer(myReducer, {});
  
  return (
    <div className="app">
    <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: "personal info", payload: {}})}>Click me!</button>
      <Modal values={myState} /> 
    </div>
  )
}

export default function Modal(props) {
    const { heading, text, action, show } = props

    <form>
      {/* content of the form (JSX) */}
    </form>
}
```